# Can location.href be recalled in another variable?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript can the page url be recalled and used in another var? Below only returns the text window.location.href not the actual url. I'm trying to force the current page url to the AddThis sharing buttons.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  var pageurl = "window.location.href";
  var addthis_share = {
  url: ""+pageurl+"" ,
  title: "Page Title"
  }
  // ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var pageurl = window.location.href;
var addthis_share = {
   url:    pageurl ,
   title: "Page Title"
}
```

Comment: thanks, this still doesn't have the same effect as manually putting the actual full url into: 
url: "http://example.com",   

possibly it is the AddThis API? putting the url in manually causes the links to populate properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "putting the url manually" ? What result do you need to get?

Comment: sorry, I mean when I use this:

  var addthis_share = {
  url:   "http://example.com/productpage" ,
  title: "My Page Title"
}
The facebook share links use my page urls properly and show the page title and image. Without typing out the full url it only shows my domain name. Since these pages are built from .net controls I can't hardcode it to every page. I'm trying to trick it by feedign it the current url :)

Comment: Hmm, what do you do with addthis_share object afterwards?

Comment: I guess it is sending it to the AddThis API using the other script on the page.

Comment: It seems as though it is working properly thanks! Some of our pages were getting confused because they did not have proper og metatags but I think this is going to do the trick.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear that you`ve figured it out!